# What does the notation $1\{x\in Q\}$ stand for?

Tags: notation

While implementing [Node Harvest](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1294167809) I stumbled over the following notation in equation (1):

$$\hat{Y}(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{g=1}^q \mu_g 1\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{Q}_g\} \mathbf{w}_g$$

I assume the expression $1\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{Q}_g\}$ evaluates to 1 if $\mathbf{x}$ is contained in $\mathcal{Q}_g$, and 0 otherwise.

If that is correct - what is the meaning of the slightly different notation in equation (2)?
$$\mu_g = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n 1\{\mathbf{X}_{i \dot{} \in \mathcal{Q}_g}\}\mathbf{Y}_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n 1\{\mathbf{X}_{i \dot{} \in \mathcal{Q}_g}\}}$$
What is the $\in \mathcal{Q}_g$ doing in the subscript of $\mathbf{X}$?

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, and that bit is not supposed to be in the subscript.

Comment: Could be... to be sure in that case, it would be nice if somebody could confirm that the notation does not make sense otherwise.

Comment: The link is broken!!

Comment: @manooooh Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps adding more details will help, such as what $i \dot{}$ refers to in $i \dot{} \in \mathcal{Q}_g$?